# Why can't Ukraine ship grain from Mariupol?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, transportation, agriculture

Russia keeps repeating that they do not want to hinder the grain shipping in any way and [that](https://news.yahoo.com/russia-says-mariupol-berdyansk-ports-132811250.html) the port in Mariupol is safe to use. Why not to say, then, let's ship from Mariupol if that port is safe?

If Russia did start seizing ships, trains or grain, arresting crews, it would at least be possible to say who is responsible. Train engineers are not soldiers.

Comment: Speculation: It could have something to do with Russia having completely destroyed that city and Russia lying about the port being safe to use

Comment: That I also suspect, that the port is not so safe to use and not exactly ready to work at full capacity.

Comment: If someone constantly lies at every occasion, what do you think how credible they are? There are *ample* risks for Ukraine to try to do this, and little to gain. Russia *always* has an agenda and tries to spin something.

Comment: Can you point to some place where Russia made this offer? Because I imagine there are other ports they control that are in better shape... The road and rail network to Mariupol was probably severely damaged in the fighting, even if the docks stand somehow.

Comment: I see Russia has posted [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Raor2b4YKDM) about shipping some steel from Mariupol to Russia, so to claim the port is operational. https://www.macaubusiness.com/first-cargo-ship-sails-from-mariupol-since-fall-to-russia-separatists/ I'd imagine howerver that with the Azov steel plants destroyed, there won't be many more shipments like that anytime soon.

Comment: Is it a serious question? Mariupol is fully destroyed, the whole region is controlled by the invador. How on hell do you imagine shipping anything throu? It's like asking why Jews haven't simply walked away from Auschwitz...

Comment: If the old classic WWII NazI would have said they always permitted and encouraged them walking away from Auschwitz ... need to ask the question wtf. But lifting all sanctions is in the package, so clear now.

Comment: Looking at a map, much of Ukraine, including presumably much of the grain-producing region looks closer to the Polish Baltic port of Gdansk than it does to Mariupol. Is not the clear long-term solution to ship via the Baltic? Though there will undoubtedly be a substantial cost in the development of facilities at the front end.

Comment: "Train engineers are not soldiers" - and Russia has no right to Ukraine, and children aren't legitimate military targets, but here we are. There'd be nothing to stop Russia from arresting them and then fabricating evidence that they were spies or saboteurs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, you have the answer in the story I've linked in your question:

> Russia blames the situation on what it says are Ukrainian mines

So basically Ukraine shipping via Mariupol would be a tacit acceptance that the (larger) port of Odessa isn't functioning because of their own/Ukrainian fault, somehow, rather than the Russian navy.

Aside from that, the Russian offer doesn't appear to be entirely unconditional. At least they communicated something like that... [via](https://apnews.com/article/russia-ukraine-turkey-middle-east-sergey-lavrov-6f0447bfa71448f2c4b8f78a7414ce45) Turkey.

> But Russia demanded that the Black Sea be demined and Turkey said allowing the Ukraine exports should be accompanied by easing Western sanctions against Russia.

Comment: I also found in the later news talks about sanction lifting appear again. This is obviously completely different conditions from "we just allow".

Comment: N.B. You watch the full video of the Russia MoD statement in that (first) story, they only talk about the rebuilt/reopened railways inside the Russian-controlled territory. Whether that's still reasonably connected with Ukrainian-controlled territory for the grain shipments to happen in quantity, apparently didn't enter into consideration.

Comment: There is no need to *tacitly* accept that the port(s) of Odessa are not functioning.  Currently that's the stated view.

Answer (score 10):

Ukraine and Russia are at war. When you are at war you try not to treat with the other party, especially with things like grain, since the other party can seize the grain for their own use. It would be like Russia exporting arms via Ukraine - foolhardy, to say the least.

Comment: If they seize the first shipment of the grain, this will make them responsible again. And it is possible to agree that, for instance, money from the grain go to some international account not to be used till the end of the war. But from the latest news Russia talks about lifting sanctions again that is not how it was initially presented.

Comment: @eee And then Russia will have a shipment of grain (maybe even the ship itself and its crew). Score: Russia 1, Ukraine 0. It wouldn't be the first time something that sneaky had been done.

Comment: @eee it is not that simple. There are not 2, but 4 countries at war now. The declared status of Peoples' republic of Donetzk and Peoples' republic of Lughansk is that Russia does not control them.

Comment: @user253751 Exactly. A stolen shipment of grain is worth plenty to Russia; Russia being held responsible for the theft is worth very little to Ukraine, considering all the things Russia is already being held responsible for.

Comment: Not really. This statement might hurt some people's feelings, but it's still a fact that they are fighting a limited war. Both militarily (Russia could have just bombed every major city completely to dust and then put their flag on the rubble, but that wasn't their goal), and economically. Russia still transports gas over Ukraine and is paying Ukraine for that service (or at least has done so for a good while even after the invasion started).

Comment: @fraxinus Two countries, and two terrorist groups sponsored by one of those countries, which it likes to pretend are also countries, just to muddy the waters a whole lot. Don't fall for it.

Comment: @user253751 I could call them 3 terrorist groups, one of them framed for being a country - and a country not fully separated from its terrorist past. Anyway, Russian government has a great deal of auditory that is OK with whatever justification they produce.

Comment: @vsz Bombing every city in UA to dust perfectly fits Russian goals. See e.g. Chechen wars. They just don't have the resources to employ this exact solution in Ukraine.

Comment: They do have the resources, for example they have the [FOAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father_of_All_Bombs), which is stronger than the smallest nuclear bombs, without being a nuclear bomb. It's just that they thought at the beginning, that an intimidating rush would be sufficient to scare their opponents to capitulation. As that didn't work out, they recently started to switch to the "bomb everything in front of us and slowly but surely inch forwards" approach. But they are *still* fighting a limited war, otherwise they could just erase Kyiv from the map.

Comment: Just a historical footnote. Britain and Germany traded materials for each other's respective arms industries because both lacked certain items to be able to continue the war without it. Both were exclusive providers of some things. They met in Switzerland to swap materiel so they could continue prosecuting the war. My guess is that they continued that because neither side could figure out who would be more disadvantaged had it stopped.

Answer (score 8):

1. Russia is lying
2. Russia destroyed Mariupol
3. Mariupol is not used for grain export; the main grain export city in Ukraine is Mykolaiv
4. Russia destroyed a huge grain export facility in Mykolaiv a week ago with a missile strike

Comment: The main harbor in Ukraine is Odessa, not Nikolev.

Comment: @convert The answer doesn't say that Mykolaiv is Ukraine's main harbor, it says it's Ukraine's "main grain export city".

Answer (score 3):

Because Mariupol is currently temporarily occupied by the invading forces of the Russian Federation.

The Russian Federation is known to be engaged in an atrocious war against Ukraine, in **violation of numerous treaties which RF is a party to** as well as in violation of some of RF's own laws.

During this war **RF has violated numerous agreements** and has not abided by terms of humanitarian corridors to which it agreed.

**RF has also engaged in acts of theft of resources** such as lumber, grain, and sheet metal.

Given these factors in their totality, it **would be patently absurd to trust** that any Ukrainian resources arriving to Mariupol, or any Ukrainian ships waiting to load those resources, would not be subjected to acts of war by the Russian military.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, things are much more complicated.

First, you should memorize, sea port is much more cargo capable than any sort of land transport.

To be exact, few Ukrainian sea ports, made more than TEN times more export/import in natural measures, than now working land transport facilities on EU border.

Second, Russian invade begins not in 2022, but much earlier - in 2014, but it is named "Anti-Terrorist operation", by Poroshenko government.

And during these years, Russia lot of times sent so named "humanitarian convoys", without Ukrainian and/or UN observers and border checks, even when constantly used railway to transport armored vehicles and weapons (so technically could send really peaceful convoys).

So, what Russia really want to do, to open large cargo port to steal Ukrainian goods and in other side, to transfer to Ukraine large quantities of weapons and military supply.

And to be honest, much number of sea mines placed by Ukrainian military, to make impossible Russian landing from sea, and second target is to make impossible to use sea ports to supply Russian military forces on Ukrainian territory.

So right answer with full truth - Ukrainian sea ports will open, when Russian military got away from Ukrainian territories, surrounding Ukrainian ports, and when Russian navy will move far enough from Ukrainian coast.
(So Ukraine will have full control over these ports)

Technically possible solution, to place UN forces, to control these territories, and to place military ships of countries non involved in conflict, to accept only humanitarian cargo.

But unfortunately, countries powerful enough to participate in these activities, avoid to do this, because Russia threatens to declare them side of conflict in such case. So I say, West avoid to declare war to Russia.

So at the moment, only possible solution, is to supply Ukrainians with modern western weapons, so Ukrainians will themselves release Ukrainian ports/coasts/territories from occupants.